# how to calculate 08:30:00 and login [ this field type is date and time ] difference?

Tags: php, mysql

I am calculating a difference between check-in time (08:30:00) it's fixed and login time will be fetched from the database. I find the difference between both of them. for eg. The person login 11:40:00 then the output will be shown as you are "3hrs 40min 00sec" late today.
I have tried this code.
in this query, i am converting login field (date and time into only time ).

```
select DATE_FORMAT(login,'%H:%i:%s')as TIMEONLY 
from attendance 
where eid='".$eid."' 
ORDER BY login DESC limit 1
```

please give me solution of a time difference.

Comment: _please give me solution_ ??? Have you tried anything for yourself?

Comment: actually sir, I try only this code. Because of I have no idea bout how to find a solution.

Comment: At least tell us if you want a SQL or PHP solution

Comment: If nobody posts an answer and all else fails, here [is a link to the MYSQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) Only as a last resort of course

Comment: ok sir. thans you for help. Sir this answer can be possible in PHP ?

Answer (score 3):

Use strtotime(string $time) method.
strtotime — Parse any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

Now you can get the difference between two timestamps and then apply normal mathematical operations to convert them into hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thank you.i will try your method.